# Remove item from array based on the Redux action payload

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

If an item is already in an array, I want to remove it, else I'd like to add it to the array. How should I go about this? I have attached incomplete code:

```
import { SELECTED_ITEM } from '../actions/type'

const INITIAL_STATE = []

export default(state = INITIAL_STATE ,action) => {  
  switch(action.type) {
    case SELECTED_ITEM:  
        state.map(function(value) {
          if(value === action.payload) {
            ?????
          }
        })
        return [...state,action.payload]
    default : return state;
  }
}
```

Do I have to loop through all values to find the item? And how can I return the new state with removed or added item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed using lodash, which is best for array iteration. For using normal loops or every i find some issue in some cases. Thus its not reliable.

```
var e = _.findIndex(state.itemList, function(o) { return o.UserID== action.payload.UserID; }); 

 if(e!==-1){
    state.itemList.splice(e, 1) 
    return { ...state, itemList: [...state.itemList] }
}
```

Comment: It's not good to mutate state. You shouldn't splice the original. You should copy it with `slice`. Also, you can do the exact same thing in pure JavaScript with `Array#findIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `Array#includes` check, then filter as needed (assuming primitive values):

```
if(state.includes(value)) {
  return state.filter(value => value !== action.payload);
}
return [...state, action.payload];
```

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash Glad to help. [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) was introduced in ES2016 so it's fairly old but is a great shortcut for `indexOf`.

Comment: How do i use Include or some similar function for and object array. Do you have any work around for this.

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash You can use `Array#find`. Then just check if the return value isn't undefined.

Comment: `state.myList.find( value => value.TableID === action.payload );`
Here it always return undefined even it has value, I have done the debug but for value its showing Unexpected End of input

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash Sorry for not responding, but if you have a specific concern I recommend asking a new question, where you can give more info and context than just a comment.

Comment: Managed using Lodash